# How to set manual scroll position when collection view loads in swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, tableheader, scroll-position

I have the main table view where collection view is settled in table view section header because of the horizontal scroll view. when I click on collection view (row 1) table view reloads. but when I click on collection view row 5, it reloads the table view and shows the collection scroll position from the beginning. Please help me out to set the manual scroll position for collection view which is inside table view.

Here is code what I am using.

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
 {
    return 2
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if section == 0
    {
        return 1
    }
    else
    {
        return 1
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if indexPath.section == 0
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "banTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! banTableViewCell

        return cell
    }
    else
    {
        if chkVal == 0
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "onepageTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! onepageTableViewCell

            return cell
        }
        else if chkVal == 1
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "onepageTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! onepageTableViewCell

            return cell
        }
        else if chkVal == 2
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "onepageTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! onepageTableViewCell

            return cell
        }
        else if chkVal == 3
        {
            print("its cming gallery there")
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "containerTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! containerTableViewCell

            return cell
        }
        else
        {
            print("its cming calendar there")
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "galTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! galTableViewCell

            return cell
        }
    }
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
    {
      if section == 0
      {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:0, height:0))
        return view
      }
      else
      {
        let SegCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "segTableViewCell") as! segTableViewCell

        SegCell.segcol.dataSource = self as UICollectionViewDataSource
        SegCell.segcol.delegate = self as UICollectionViewDelegate
        SegCell.segcol.isPagingEnabled = true
        SegCell.segcol.isScrollEnabled = true
        SegCell.segcol.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
        SegCell.segcol.register(UINib(nibName: "segCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "segCollectionViewCell")
        // Initialization code

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)
        SegCell.segcol.scrollToItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.right, animated: false)
        return SegCell
    }
}

  //Collection View Set

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
  {
     return 5
  }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "segCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! segCollectionViewCell

    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        cell.TextSeg.text = "FITNESS REPORT CARD"
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1
    {
        cell.TextSeg.text = "FITNESS STATS"
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 2
    {
        cell.TextSeg.text = "DIET & NUTRITION"
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 3
    {
        cell.TextSeg.text = "GALLERY"
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 4
    {
        cell.TextSeg.text = "CALENDAR"
    }
    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSize(width:150, height:46)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        tbl.reloadData()
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1
    {
        tbl.reloadData()
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 2
    {
        tbl.reloadData()
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 3
    {
        tbl.reloadData()
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 4
    {
        tbl.reloadData()
    }
}
```

It's not setting the scroll position in the collection view.

Thanks

Comment: when I click on collection view ?? Where s that action ?

Comment: collection views delegate and data source method will be called for setting the nib.

Comment: U r clicking, collectionView's cell right? Then how TableView again reloads? So that only I have asked ur action method

Comment: Please check, I have edited the question.

Comment: Post ur required screen u need..!! UI...

Comment: First why do you have nested `if-elseif-elseif`, inside `didSelectedItemAt`. They all do same thing. And for scrolling see [scrollToItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618046-scrolltoitem)

Comment: because every time different cell is loading when clicking on didSelectedItemAt.